# Unable to set up Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I am having a couple problems setting up Jupyter Notebook. I have been over the documentation many times and still haven't gotten it working. I am running Anaconda on my Windows 7 (and 10 on my other computer - having same problem) workstation. I am unable to open Jupyter Notebooks easily. I have tried the following in the cmd prompt: `ipython notebook`, `jupyter notebook`, `jupyter-notebook`, `ipython`, and `jupyter` and I get `'XXXXXX' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I can `cd` into `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts` and then run `jupyter notebook` and it works. There are two problems with this: First, it's a band-aid that just covers up an underlying problem and second it opens to `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts` and I can't navigate to where my `.ipynb` files are. I don't have an IPython Notebook launcher icon to change to directory per the follow instructions:

```
• Copy the IPython Notebook launcher from the menu to the desktop.
• Right click on the new launcher and change the “Start in” field by pasting the full path of the folder which will contain all the notebooks.
```

I also have spyder install and it appears to be working perfectly.

In my `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts` folder, I see everything I would expect: `ipython.exe`, `jupyter.exe`, `jupyter-notebook.exe`, and a lot more. My path variables contain everything I've seen suggested online: `C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin`
These were added automatically from the installation so I don't think there's a typo.

Any thoughts you have would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just needed to restart the computer. That fixed everything.

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things. Glad you solved the problem.